# Blazor page routing integration into existing razor page app

Tags: .net, razor-pages, blazor-server-side

I followed the documentation here as best as I could. [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#use-routable-components-in-a-razor-pages-app)

I've added App.razor, _Imports.razor and _Host.cshtml as directed.
[image: _host]
[image: app.razor]

[image]

the test page is this
[image]

I've updated the startup blazorHub() and MapFallbackToPage() endpoints

[image]

If I browser to existing razor Page ClientDashboard.cshtml and have it load the component  the blazor page will load and function. So I know my blazor.js is loading correctly

```
@(await @Html.RenderComponentAsync<Components.ClientDashboard.ClientManagement>(RenderMode.Server, new{clientId = @Model.ClientID}))
```

But I'm not wanting to bypass this and just actual routing to navigate to my blazor pages localhost.com/ClientDashboard/42 for example.

But I'm currently getting page error when trying to browse to https://localhost:5001/TestRouting page

[image]
[image]

I'm unsure what I'm missing or how to debug this and guidance would be appreciated!

**Update**
I tried PMC suggestion but got different error page came up blank
with this error in browser tools

[image]

[image]

**Update 2**

Moved all files into the Pages directory just in case there was an issue with the locations.  Also tried a few versions of the host.cshtml

[image]

still, get null reference exception either directly on the page or in the console of the browser.

Referenced PMC [Guide](https://www.programmerjourney.com/integrate-blazor-into-razor-pages/) for the above different tweaks

I'm sure I'm missing something stupid here I just can't seem to figure out what.

**Update 3**

I updated _host file to match Qing Guo most of the change listed I had already done.

Default _layout page loads but not the blazor component I'm trying

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change

```
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(App).Assembly">
```

to this in your App.Razor file

```
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
```

I followed this [guide](https://www.programmerjourney.com/integrate-blazor-into-razor-pages/) and it worked for me with Razor Pages on Dot net 5.0, to implement Blazor components with a direct route also.

Comment: it loads page but blank content this time with null exception error in-browser tools I included screen in question edit

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference - but I have App.razor,_Imports & _Host file all in the Pages folder,  not root folder.

Comment: will try that next

Comment: Moved everything to the pages directory. and even tried few different tweaks to _host.cshtml still getting errors the directly to the page or in-browser tool console . see above for update screen shot

Comment: By any chance is there a null parameter, or some prop not initialised inside the component? You are passing ClientId I can see when loading from another page, but have you tried to remove params for testing? It might not be getting the route params when routing directly. Maybe post the component code to see if anyone can spot issues with that.

Answer (score 2):

Try the work demo as below, you can refer to it:

**Step One: Blazor support**

First, you have to add Blazor support into your application. This support will allow you to render Blazor components from a Razor page.

1.Startup.cs:

Services.AddServerSideBlazor(); is needed in ConfigureServices and endpoints.MapBlazorHub(); in Configure:

2._Layout.cshtml:

Blazor’s JS-library is needed in order to enable server side Blazor. This can be added into _Layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

3._Imports.razor:

We also need a new file called _Imports.razor. This should be added into the Pages-folder._Imports.razor is used to set the using-statements for your Blazor components. We can start with the following:

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
```

4.Counter.razor:

And that’s it.We now should have a working Blazor-support in our existing app. We can test this out by copy-pasting the classic Counter-component into our app:

```
@page "/counter"
 
<h1>Counter</h1>
 
<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>
 
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
 
@code {
    int currentCount = 0;
 
    void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

5.Privacy.cshtml:

editing Privacy.cshtml to include the Counter component:

```
@page
@model PrivacyModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Privacy Policy";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
 
<p>Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>
 
<component>@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Counter>(RenderMode.Server))</component>
```

**Step Two: Blazor Pages support**

1.App.razor:

Create a new App.razor file into Pages-folder. The Router component is defined in App.razor:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
 
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="routeData"/>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <h1>Page not found</h1>
        <p>Sorry, but there's nothing here!</p>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

2._Host.cshtml:

In the _Host.cshtml we can define the layout which in our case will be the same as the Razor pages are using,_Host.cshtml contains the call to Html.RenderComponentAsync:

```
@page "/blazor"
 
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
 
<app>
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.Server))
</app>
```

3.Startup.cs:

a small addition to Startup.cs’ Configure-method. We previously added MapBlazorHub but now we also add call to MapFallbackToPage and point it to the new _Host.cshtml:

```
endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
```

4._Layout.cshtml:

Now we just need to test our setup. Add Blazor page Counter into your layout by editing Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml:

```
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/Counter">Blazor Counter</a>
                        </li>
```

When we now start out application, we should have a working Blazor page in our Razor Pages application,and we didn’t break the support for adding Blazor components into Razor Pages.

Result:
[image]

Comment: I've done everything you have listed, it still doesn't load when I try to navigate to localhost https://localhost:5001/TestRouting which is why I'm so confused.  

Step one: still works... as one of my Razor Page will still load a functioning Blazor component. It's just step two that I seem to be running into the null reference issue when I go to test all those settings. just doesn't make sense  I've added the response I'm getting now after matching my _host file to your example

Comment: Ok this is screwy as hell for some reason when I start from a scratch new project it works .... but isn't with my exiting app sighs going to have to compare them and if I can figure out the differences sighs

Comment: I wish you success and good luck.